# How to get ID and Title from element that is auto generated

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get a ID and Title from a element that is not in my code but when my website is load then appear.

when I inspect the  code and I can see the id

I used  `getelementbyid` and `(#id).attr("ïd")`   but did not work  :/

Comment: getelementbyid is for if you already have the id and want the select the element. Do you have siblings you can refer to?

Comment: First check if the document is loaded using $(document).ready(function() { /* code here */ });

Comment: Try getting them inside window `onload` function: `window.onload = function() { var el = document.getElementById('yourId'); }`

Comment: you can show this "element" from your website load?

Comment: @aManHasNoName  i used   $(document).ready(function() {

window.onload = function() { var el = document.getElementById('u_0_2'); }

});  and got  el is not defined

Comment: Nope! Use either DOM ready or window load function. NOT Both.

Comment: You should also paste complete HTML + JS code you are trying, so that you may get better help from SO.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
var eleID = $(document).find("#id").attr("title");
```

Comment: var eleID = $(document).find("#u_0_2").attr("title");

    alert(eleID);    i got undefined

Comment: check document is loaded  $(function() { var eleID = $(document).find("#u_0_2").attr("title"); });